# USB C in Skoda Kamiq

Tags: skoda

I am thinking on buying new [Skoda Kamiq](https://www.skoda-auto.com/models/range/kamiq). They are offering USB C docks in the car. Does somebody know how strong USB C chargers are there? Can I charge my macbookpro 2019?

Comment: I tested with usb meter and max output is 15W

Comment: At 15w, it might be possible to charge your MacBook Pro...but it'd take _forever_.